# How can I make the color points in ChromaticityPlot[] joined?

Tags: plotting, color

So I'm using [`ChromaticityPlot[]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ChromaticityPlot.html) to plot some colors as points:

```
ChromaticityPlot @ {XYZColor[{0.3962764261624673, 0.3985866722291033, 
  0.20513690160842935`}], XYZColor[{0.1882738217108961, 
  0.17432829223539636`, 0.6373978860537075}], XYZColor[{
  0.27512411027344047`, 0.32422074043525423`, 
  0.4006551492913053}], XYZColor[{0.49021477022201715`, 
  0.4671104708306489, 0.042674758947334}], XYZColor[{
  0.2522112854045193, 0.13716125248343866`, 
  0.610627462112042}], XYZColor[{0.21702686377542535`, 
  0.37187565542299844`, 0.41109748080157626`}], XYZColor[{
  0.4519208585586688, 0.4619745394044663, 0.08610460203686487}]}
```

Which produces:

[image: plot]

(I apologize if the points are a little hard to see.)

Is there a way to connect these points in the order of the list they were passed to `ChromaticityPlot`? If it were something like `ListPlot`, I'd just used `Joined -> True`, but it appears that that's not an option for `ChromaticityPlot`. I checked the Details and Options section of the doc page, but couldn't find anything.

If this isn't possible directly with `ChromaticityPlot`, my next guess would be doing something where you make a plot of the points and connect them (pretty easy) and then combine that image with a blank `ChromaticityPlot` such that the points are in the right positions they would be with `ChromaticityPlot`, but I'm not sure how to do that part smoothly.

edit:

kglr's answer *almost* works, but I noticed an error when I implemented it. Copying the color coordinates isn't working right now so I've attached pictures. Here are the colors I'm passing to `ChromaticityPlot`, in this order:

[image: colors]

And they produce this plot:

[image: the plot]

Basically, they are in the order of the "spiral" you see, which is the order I want the lines to connect them in. But:

```
Show[cp, Epilog -> Line[Cases[cp, Point[x_] :> x, Infinity]]]
```

produces:

[image: attempt]

So clearly `ChromaticityPlot[]` indexes the points in its own order when it plots them, and the `Epilog` code references that order.

How can I plot them in the original order?

Here is the very long list of color coordinates:

```
{XYZColor[{0.3962764261624673, 0.3985866722291033, 
  0.20513690160842935`}], XYZColor[{0.41989580004282673`, 
  0.4125447180532846, 0.16755948190388859`}], XYZColor[{
  0.4482129325305696, 0.42651818489027327`, 
  0.12526888257915705`}], XYZColor[{0.4811531561718577, 
  0.4381504285364153, 0.08069641529172708}], XYZColor[{
  0.5143601128769091, 0.44025669186403676`, 
  0.04538319525905425}], XYZColor[{0.528760139180238, 
  0.4145525405870635, 0.05668732023269851}], XYZColor[{
  0.4803629345878539, 0.3360211576923957, 
  0.18361590771975042`}], XYZColor[{0.35750986685641445`, 
  0.22882116488660556`, 0.41366896825698}], XYZColor[{
  0.2476518543205762, 0.16907253110576892`, 
  0.5832756145736548}], XYZColor[{0.19861762041302972`, 
  0.1634606041596999, 0.6379217754272702}], XYZColor[{
  0.1875416285273102, 0.1788798412802935, 
  0.6335785301923963}], XYZColor[{0.19135310967885746`, 
  0.19759559604937496`, 0.6110512942717676}], XYZColor[{
  0.199758020524691, 0.2145677412332461, 
  0.5856742382420629}], XYZColor[{0.20906919798555915`, 
  0.2292323092320303, 0.5616984927824105}], XYZColor[{
  0.21820602877387354`, 0.24226526538569332`, 
  0.5395287058404332}], XYZColor[{0.22708567876240668`, 
  0.2546217373697826, 0.5182925838678107}], XYZColor[{
  0.23602526621541525`, 0.2672649432218379, 
  0.49670979056274667`}], XYZColor[{0.24551029106977174`, 
  0.2810589158427847, 0.47343079308744357`}], XYZColor[{
  0.2560852349903017, 0.2966741794557585, 
  0.4472405855539397}], XYZColor[{0.2682779238951681, 
  0.31448277231441685`, 0.4172393037904151}], XYZColor[{
  0.2825298023422926, 0.3344663811508697, 
  0.3830038165068378}], XYZColor[{0.2991300743797761, 
  0.3561737959379507, 0.34469612968227326`}], XYZColor[{
  0.31816383976198165`, 0.37875569437249934`, 
  0.3030804658655192}], XYZColor[{0.3394882438812166, 
  0.4010818563300672, 0.2594298997887162}], XYZColor[{
  0.36274481654029095`, 0.4219134037447116, 
  0.21534177971499754`}], XYZColor[{0.3874012070007992, 
  0.44007475578212696`, 0.1725240372170738}], XYZColor[{
  0.4127991754914565, 0.454565651550761, 
  0.13263517295778254`}], XYZColor[{0.43817789531082135`, 
  0.4645780300397474, 0.09724407464943127}], XYZColor[{
  0.4626457533061279, 0.4694204554873389, 
  0.06793379120653323}], XYZColor[{0.48508605343546224`, 
  0.46838431965922356`, 0.04652962690531424}], XYZColor[{
  0.504000013354655, 0.4606063756512746, 
  0.03539361099407013}], XYZColor[{0.5173231956248223, 
  0.4450040365334342, 0.037672767841743386`}], XYZColor[{
  0.5223206336107772, 0.4203977920883609, 
  0.057281574300861685`}], XYZColor[{0.5157833773795454, 
  0.3859716213212005, 0.09824500129925415}], XYZColor[{
  0.49484180809674294`, 0.3421568586717254, 
  0.16300133323153168`}], XYZColor[{0.45851571455902984`, 
  0.29167965340615476`, 0.24980463203481543`}], XYZColor[{
  0.4093472781509597, 0.23992274244067863`, 
  0.3507299794083615}], XYZColor[{0.3536007952377925, 
  0.19366703703382868`, 0.4527321677283788}], XYZColor[{
  0.29912267846630747`, 0.15855576989396697`, 
  0.5423215516397255}], XYZColor[{0.2522112854045193, 
  0.13716125248343866`, 0.610627462112042}]}
```

Comment: `Show[cp, Epilog->Line[Cases[cp, Point[x_]:>x, Infinity]]]`?

Comment: To post the colors you have, select the list of colors and then right-click: Copy As > Input Text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:**  To connect the points in the original order, use `ChromaticityPlot` separately for each color, extract the projected coordinates and combine them:

```
pts=Sequence@@@(ChromaticityPlot[#,Appearance->None][[1,2,1,2]]&/@colors);
Show[cp, Epilog->{Thick,Line[pts,VertexColors->colors]} ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Using OP's new list of colors, we get

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

Original post:

```
colors= {XYZColor[{0.3962764261624673, 0.3985866722291033, 
  0.20513690160842935`}], XYZColor[{0.1882738217108961, 
  0.17432829223539636`, 0.6373978860537075}], XYZColor[{
  0.27512411027344047`, 0.32422074043525423`, 
  0.4006551492913053}], XYZColor[{0.49021477022201715`, 
  0.4671104708306489, 0.042674758947334}], XYZColor[{
  0.2522112854045193, 0.13716125248343866`, 
  0.610627462112042}], XYZColor[{0.21702686377542535`, 
  0.37187565542299844`, 0.41109748080157626`}], XYZColor[{
  0.4519208585586688, 0.4619745394044663, 0.08610460203686487}]};

cp= ChromaticityPlot[colors];


Show[cp, Epilog->Line[Cases[cp, Point[x_]:>x, Infinity]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Show[cp, Epilog->{Thick,Line[Cases[cp, Point[x_]:>x, Infinity], 
                  VertexColors->(Join@@(Partition[colors,2,1]))]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I'm out of votes, so here's a suggestion: how about using the specified colors as `VertexColors` for the line?

Comment: @J.M. good idea; i will try.

Comment: Excellent, this works brilliantly!

Comment: Wait, I'm sorry, I have to un-accept this answer: I was actually implementing this and realized it's not totally right! It connects the points, but based on the order ChromaticityPlot has them in, not the order they were passed to it in! I've edited my OP to reflect the problem.

Comment: @YungHummmma, please see the update.

Answer (score 4):

By manually [converting the `XYZColor[]` colors into *xy*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIE_1931_color_space#CIE_xy_chromaticity_diagram_and_the_CIE_xyY_color_space), we can generate the line easily.

```
cols = {XYZColor[...], ...}; (* your list of colors *)

ChromaticityPlot[cols, Epilog -> {Thick, Line[Most[Normalize[#, Total]] & @@@ cols,
                                              VertexColors -> cols]}]
```

[image: chromaticity diagram with joined points]

If the colors given are not XYZ colors, use `ColorConvert[]` first.

---

For completeness, here is the corresponding 3D plot with joined points:

```
Show[ChromaticityPlot3D[cols, PlotStyle -> PointSize[Medium]], 
     Graphics3D[{Thick, Line[Prepend[Most[Normalize[#, Total]], #[[2]]] & @@@ cols, 
                             VertexColors -> cols]}]]
```

[image: 3D chromaticity diagram with joined points]